# Tab Align Wrapped Line of Code upon Printing in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Lets say I'm printing some code in Eclipse.  By default Eclipse prints wrapped lines at the beginning of the line (1st example), which can make the code hard to read. Is there any way to get Eclipse to align wrapped lines with the correct indentation when printing (2nd example)?

**Default Eclipse Print Formatting**

```
     for (List<String> text in data.rows()){
          if (text =="this string" || text =="that string" || text =="some other
     this string"{//do something }

    }
```

**Can I get Eclipse to Align wrapped Line with the Correct Indentation?**

```
    for (List<String> text in data.rows()){
        if (text =="this string" || text =="that string" || text =="some   other       
        this string"
        {//do something }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Eclipse to format your code by going to Window ->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter, and then on right side click "Edit" , it will bring something like below:

[image]

You can set your style using this.